# Error al verificar valor con JavaScript y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, validación

Tengo un tabla en donde se genera un código y se envía por email, como una validación y tengo un problema con Javascript y es que no sé como comparar esos valores, hasta ahora pude hacer esto:

base de datos

```
id | usuario | codigo
---------------------
 1 | Antonia | ah5j%M
```

código

```
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$fila = $sql->fetch();
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="formulario">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" placeholder="Codigo" autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" name="validar" class="btn btn-primary">Validar</button>
</form>


<script>
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hiciste Click');

    var datos = new FormData(formulario);

    console.log(datos);
    console.log(datos.get('code'));

    fetch('',{ // no sé que dato tomar
        method = 'POST',
        body = datos
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
})
</script>
```

Sé que no es mucho, pero no estoy muy ducha con JavaScript y no sé que datos tomar en `fetch`. Espero me ayuden a entender un poco más.

Gracias.

Comment: Debemos empezar recordando que asi no se construye un objeto en js (`{  }`), ese es uno de los posibles errores.

Comment: El primer parámetro de `fetch` es la URL a donde se enviará la petición y, si todo va bien, en el segundo `.then()` deberías poder ver la respuesta en la consola del navegador. Haz las pruebas necesarias y, si todavía tienes dudas, edita la pregunta para agregar lo que veas en la consola después de haber hecho la petición, ya sean errores, texto u objetos.

Comment: Parecería que tu código PHP está en el mismo archivo donde está el código Javascript donde lanzas el `fetch` ¿? ¿Es por eso por lo que no hay URL en la petición `fetch`? El propósito de `fetch`  es traer datos que están en el servidor, y debes poner la URL donde están esos datos, que **debe ser un archivo distinto del que hace la petición `fetch`**.

Comment: @A.Cedano claro, esta todo dentro del mismo PHP y veo que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Ese concepto debe quedar claro: `fetch` existe para intercambiar recursos entre **cliente** (donde está tu código Javascript y escribes la solicitud) y  **servidor** (donde está el código PHP que en este caso consulta a la BD y devuelve los datos). No tiene ningún sentido plantear una petición `fetch` con el código de servidor en el mismo archivo que contiene la petición. Otro ejemplo: con `fetch` puedes obtener desde el cliente datos que son servidos por una API o Servicio Web. Para más detalles, [consulta la doc en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).